# Python matplotlib - Combine categorical background along with scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to figure out a right library in Python to create a complex plot which looks something like this:

[image: Plot to be created]

The plot background is classified into 3 regions (Yellow, Red, Green) based on conditions of X and Y. For Example :

- For Green area: (`X<=1` and `Y<=1`) OR (`X<0.5`)
- For Yellow area: (`0.5<X<1` and `Y>1`) OR (`1<X<1.5` and `1<Y<3`) OR (`1.5<X<2` and `Y<2`)
  Similarly for the Red area....

These conditions remain the same throughout my application.
I have the coordinates in a csv file and know how to plot the scatter plot. But I am stuck because of the background color code.

Is there a Python library that I can use to plot the scatter plot along with these grid colors at the back. I checked many sites and questions but unfortunately found nothing useful/related.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your code with example input, expected output, actual output, and how this differed from your expectation. I suggest reading again [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you can use `ax.axvspan` or `patches.Rectangle((1,3), 1, 4, color="red",  alpha=0.50)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's `imshow()` with a 2D array.  The coordinates of the 2D array can be created using `np.meshgrid()`. These coordinates will be the lower left vertices of each grid cell. They can address into the 2D array, e.g. with `[((X < 1) & (Y < 1)) | (X < 0.5)]`. Filling the 2D arrays with `0`, `1` and `2` at the appropriate locations allows to create the background.

Matplotlib's `scatter()` will place scatter dots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

xvals = np.random.uniform(0, 3, 50)
yvals = np.random.uniform(0, 4.2, 50)
X1d = np.arange(0, 3.0001, 0.25)
Y1d = np.arange(0, 4.2001, 0.20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X1d, Y1d)
backgr = np.full_like(X, 2)
backgr[((X < 1.5) & (Y < 3)) | ((X < 2) & (Y < 2)) | (X < 1)] = 1
backgr[((X < 1) & (Y < 1)) | (X < 0.5)] = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xvals, yvals, color='black')
cmap = ListedColormap(['lime', 'gold', 'crimson'])
ax.imshow(backgr[:-1, :-1], cmap=cmap, alpha=0.2, extent=[0, X1d[-1], 0, Y1d[-1]], origin='lower', aspect='auto')
ax.set_xticks(X1d, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(Y1d, minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.grid(True, which='both', lw=1, ls=':', color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a prompt response! It solves my problem :)